# tikzpicture missing category

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having trouble drawing a tikzpicture. One of the categories is missing. Does anybody know how to increase the canvas width?

Thanks in advance!

```
\pgfplotstableread[row sep =\\, col sep = &]{
Level   &Rating \\
0   &2.875  \\
1   &2.954545   \\
2   &2.571429   \\
3   &2.888889   \\
4   &2.923077   \\
5   &2.684211   \\
6   &2.8125 \\
7   &3.043478   \\
8   &3.611111   \\
9   &1.9375 \\
10  &2.833333   \\
11  &2.3125 \\
12  &1.666667   \\
13  &2.684211   \\
14  &2.6    \\
15  &2.75   \\
16  &2.578947   \\
17  &3.333333   \\
18  &2.333333   \\
19  &3  \\
20  &3.3    \\
21  &3.842105   \\
22  &2.916667   \\
23  &2.380952   \\
24  &1.933333   \\
25  &2.6    \\
26  &3.047619   \\
27  &2.833333   \\
28  &2.047619   \\
29  &2.421053   \\
}\mydata

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\tiny
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.75\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=12, transform shape]
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar interval=0.5,
            symbolic x coords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29},
            xtick=data,
            ]
            \addplot table[x = Level, y = Rating]{\mydata};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Raw Results of the User Ratings}
    \label{fig:experiment1results}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: As always on this site please post a full (but minimal) example instead of sniplets like this where we have to guess the document class and preamble. Having a full example others can just copy and test as is.

Comment: Additionally what `categories` are you refering to here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! If I understand the problem correctly, your complaint is about not seeing a bar for the last table row, the one with x = 29. This is expected because you are using `ybar interval`, as opposed to `ybar`. Quoting the `pgfplots` manual (section *Bar Plots*
):

> `\addplot+[ybar interval]`
>
> This plot type produces vertical bars with width (and shift) relatively to intervals of coordinates.
>
> There is one conceptional difference when working with intervals: an interval is defined by *two* coordinates. Since `ybar` has one value for each interval, the *i*th bar is defined by
>
> 1. the *y* value of the *i*th coordinates,
> 2. the *x* value of the *i*th coordinate as left interval boundary,
> 3. the *x* value of the (*i*+1)th coordinate as right interval boundary.
>
> Consequently, there is *one coordinate too much:* the last coordinate will *only* be used to determine the interval width; its *y* value doesn’t influence the bar appearance.

This explains why, in your example, no bar is drawn for the (29, 2.421053) coordinate pair. I believe what you want is the `/pgfplots/ybar` style.

The example below uses `/pgfplots/ybar`. You can tune the width of bars using `/pgf/bar width` (see below). In order to keep this possibility while switching to the latest `pgfplots` API (which I did using `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`), I removed your `symbolic x coords={...}`, which doesn't appear very useful here. Indeed, the x coordinates are all numeric and evenly spaced in your data.

If you want a different number of minor ticks between consecutive major ticks, you can use `minor x tick num` as shown below. If you do so, you may need to also change the major tick label font size; this can be done with `x tick label style={font=\small}`, for instance.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\, col sep=&]{
Level & Rating     \\
0     & 2.875      \\
1     & 2.954545   \\
2     & 2.571429   \\
3     & 2.888889   \\
4     & 2.923077   \\
5     & 2.684211   \\
6     & 2.8125     \\
7     & 3.043478   \\
8     & 3.611111   \\
9     & 1.9375     \\
10    & 2.833333   \\
11    & 2.3125     \\
12    & 1.666667   \\
13    & 2.684211   \\
14    & 2.6        \\
15    & 2.75       \\
16    & 2.578947   \\
17    & 3.333333   \\
18    & 2.333333   \\
19    & 3          \\
20    & 3.3        \\
21    & 3.842105   \\
22    & 2.916667   \\
23    & 2.380952   \\
24    & 1.933333   \\
25    & 2.6        \\
26    & 3.047619   \\
27    & 2.833333   \\
28    & 2.047619   \\
29    & 2.421053   \\
}\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar, bar width=1.0,
    xtick={0,5,...,30},
    minor x tick num=4, % major divisions divided in 5 minor ones
    ]
  \addplot table[x=Level, y=Rating]{\mydata};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I needed :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. :-)